# Parse HTTP_USER_AGENT in pl/sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

HTTP_USER_AGENT

```
declare
 t_browser varchar2(250);

BEGIN
t_browser := OWA_UTIL.get_cgi_env('HTTP_USER_AGENT');

return t_browser;
END;
```

I'm trying to do it like that but it cant captured with LIKE. I need to parse it.

```
 IF OWA_UTIL.GET_CGI_ENV('HTTP_USER_AGENT') LIKE '%MSIE 7.0%' THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('1');

 ELSIF OWA_UTIL.GET_CGI_ENV('HTTP_USER_AGENT') LIKE '%Firefox/3%' THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('3');'
```

Instead of

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36

I want to make it like that simple.

> Chrome.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Can you explain exactly what problem you have?  Is `OWA_UTIL.get_cgi_env('HTTP_USER_AGENT')` not returning the value you expect?  Is one of your `like` statements not doing what you expect?  Something else?

Comment: Hey Justin, my return value is like 

 " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
   Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36 "  

     that, but I want to make it simple just like 'Chrome'.

Comment: I will return to browser info to user, if user using IE there will be a alert message,so for that I have to catch which browser usings so

Comment: To catch browser name inside of that long information message I guess I have to make in pieces it with parsing or INSTR,substr functions.

Comment: `like '%Chrome%'` would obviously work for that string.  Note that parsing user-agent strings gets pretty complicated because lots of different agents send lots of different things and lots of different people want to put them in different buckets.

Comment: Actually I tried 'like' condition in my codes but with your kindly answers helped me to solve minor problem. I got it perfectly. Thanks for answers. I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `LIKE` keyword in a `IF` statement.

Use an SQL statement instead:

```
DECLARE
 check NUMBER;
BEGIN

    SELECT 1
    INTO check
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE OWA_UTIL.GET_CGI_ENV('HTTP_USER_AGENT') LIKE '%MSIE 7.0%';


    IF check = 1 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('1');
    ELSE
        ...
    END IF;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **OWA_UTIL.GET_CGI_ENV('HTTP_USER_AGENT')**

```
DECLARE

    l_browser_agent nvarchar2(2000) := OWA_UTIL.GET_CGI_ENV('HTTP_USER_AGENT');
    l_browser_type nvarchar2(2000) := 'UNKNOWN';
    l_browser_type_color nvarchar2(2000) := 'secondary';
    l_version nvarchar2(2000);
    
    l_secure_browser boolean := false;
 
 BEGIN
    
    IF l_browser_agent LIKE '%Chrome/%' THEN    
    
        l_browser_type := 'Chrome';
        l_version := SUBSTR(l_browser_agent, INSTR(l_browser_agent,'Chrome/')+7,3);        
        
        -- Secure Chrome browser are over version 40 
        IF (to_number(l_version)> 40) THEN
            l_secure_browser := true;     
        END IF;
        
    ELSIF l_browser_agent LIKE '%MSIE %' THEN  
            
        l_browser_type := 'Internet Explorer';        
        l_version := SUBSTR(l_browser_agent, INSTR(l_browser_agent,'MSIE ')+5,3);     
        
        -- All Internet Explorer browser are in-sequre 
        
    ELSIF l_browser_agent LIKE '%Firefox/%' THEN    
        l_browser_type := 'Firefox';        
        l_version := SUBSTR(l_browser_agent, INSTR(l_browser_agent,'Firefox/')+8,2); 
        
        -- Secure Firefox browser are over version 60 
        IF (to_number(l_version)> 60) THEN
            l_secure_browser := true;     
        END IF;
    ELSE
    
        l_browser_type := 'UNKNOWN ['||l_browser_agent||']';
    END IF;

    IF not l_secure_browser THEN
        l_browser_type_color := 'danger';    
    ELSE
        l_browser_type_color := 'success';     
    END IF;        
    
 END;
```